# I need a bottom in the fancybox?

Tags: scroll, fancybox

I have a really big page cause I have the different sections on the same page. The problem is when I active the fancybox that is applied in some images I can scroll down up to the end of the page.

Isn't there any way that when I get to the bottom of the fancybox I can't go down?

I've also proved disabling the scroll of the page when the fancybox is open but the problem is that is that this disables the scroll of the fancybox too...

I need some help please